# getElementByClassName gives empty array but chrome console gives all elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get all the elements with class name "game-image" and put it into an array so I can loop through it. In my `javascript` file I have the following:

```
var gameImages = document.getElementsByClassName("game-image");
console.log(gameImages.length)
console.log(gameImages)
```

And I have multiple images on my `HTML` file like this(yes pokemon)

```
<img class="game-image" id="bulbasaur" src="images/pokeball.jpg">
```

Now when I check dev tools console on chrome, the console displays `0` for length and `[]` for gameImages.  But when I type `console.log(gameImages)` into the console, I get the array I was trying to get. Anyone know why?

This same code worked on one of my other projects but not this one.

Comment: put code inside `window.onload = function(){   // code here...  };`

Comment: script was in the header -.- I was dumb.

Comment: another case of premature evaluation